# Backend for autosuggest for fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, autosuggest

I want to create an autosuggest for a fulltext search with AJAX, PHP & MySQL.

I am looking for the right way to implement the backend. While the user is typing, the input field should give him suggests. Suggests should be generated from text entrys in a table.

Some information for this entrys: They are stored in fulltext, generated from PDF with 3-4 pages each. There not more than 100 entrys for now and will reach a maximum of 2000 in the next few years.

If the user starts to type, the word he is typing should be completed with a word which is stored in the DB, sorted by occurrences descending. Next step is to suggest combinations with other words, witch have a high occurrence in the entrys matching the first word. Surely you can compare it to Google autosuggest.

I am thinking about **3 different** ways to implement this:

1. Generate an index via cronjob, witch counts occurrences of words and combinations over night. The user searches on this index.
2. I do a live search within the entrys with an 'LIKE "%search%"' function. Then I look for the word after the this and GROUP them by occurrence.
3. I create a logfile for all user searches, and look for good combinations like in 1), so the search gets more intelligent with each search action.

What is the best way to start with this? The search should be fast and performant. 
Is there a better possibility I did not think about?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use mysql's MATCH() AGAINST() (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST('search')
ORDER BY MATCH(column) AGAINST('search')
```

Another advantage is that you could further tweak the importance of words being searched for (if neccessary), like:

```
MATCH(column) AGAINST('>important <lessimportant') IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

Or say that certain words of the search term are to be required, whilst others may not be present in the result, eg:

```
MATCH(column) AGAINST('+required -prohibited') IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

Comment: Good solution for fulltext search, but With this solution I get the whole entry back. I want to complete single words for the autosuggest. How do I get well matching words from the same entrys?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the idea no 1 is the best. By the way, dont't forget to eliminate stopwords from autosuggest (an, the, by, ...).